# Most common Präteritum / Imperfekt forms in written German?

Tags: verb, preterite, irregular-verb

I have a German examination in two weeks, which includes two comprehensions of about CEFR-B1 level. (An example of this exam from 2012 can be found [here](http://examinations.ie/archive/exampapers/2012/LC011ALP000EV.pdf).)

I have worked up to over 2000 of the most frequent German words using a word frequency list, and I have also done over 2000 of the topic-related vocabulary that comes up in the exam. This includes infinitives of all the verbs that would come up in either list.

The problem is: I've just realised that there are a lot of irregular forms of the Präteritum that I don't recognise. This makes it difficult, since the Präteritum is used quite frequently in these comprehensions, and many of them are irregular. I haven't had much luck finding a list of the most common *irregular* verbs, and I want to use my time wisely. I have been given a list of over 100 irregular verbs and their Präteritum forms, but they are in alphabetical order and this is really unhelpful.

I am wondering if anyone has **a list of the top thirty or so most-common irregular verbs, along with their Präteritum form**? Or, does anyone have **any other suggestions** as to how to get around this problem? You may be able to gauge if you take a quick glance at the comprehensions in the example above.

Also: it occurred to me that the most common irregular verbs may not also have the most *commonly used Präteritum forms*.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can come up with your own ranking. Take each of the 100 3rd-person preterite forms, add the pronoun "er", throw each one ("er kam", "er ging", "er fand")  at google, write down the number of search results, and rank accordingly.

Comment: @elena That's a pretty good suggestion, and that's what I've just done. I was kind of hoping there would be some intelligent suggestion that wasn't as laborious, but I guess not! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if the suggestion of elena is OK for you, I would recommend to use the [Wortschatz-Portal der Uni Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/).

> Wort:  kam
>   Anzahl:  150853
>   Häufigkeitsklasse: 6 (d.h. der ist ca. 2^6 mal häufiger als das gesuchte Wort)
>
> Wort:  ging
>   Anzahl:  108980
>   Häufigkeitsklasse: 7 (d.h. der ist ca. 2^7 mal häufiger als das gesuchte Wort)

Comment: I really would have preferred to use that portal. But I've already used Google to do it. While I would have preferred the better source, I don't think it's a huge issue, do you? As in, I just wanted to spend my time on the most common ones. I will probably get them all done in the time, but I wanted to have the more likely ones known so I could be most familiar with them. I have the list pasted up: [link](http://pastebin.com/WbuFBJ42), in the Google search-frequency order. Would you be able to take a quick glance to ensure it covers all the bases and looks about right? Thanks.

Comment: @EdmundHeaphy I wouldn't say that this list is completely wrong but I'm pretty sure that your results are still not good enough to rely on those. Have another look at ["er litt"](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=%22er+litt%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest). Don't look at the number but at the actual results. I'm pretty sure the ranking of *leiden* is far too high. Anyway, I don't think that for your use case the actual ranking is that important. You covered a lot of common words. I can't tell if you missed any.

Comment: Hmmmmm. I had a look at the results for "er litt", and they doesn't seem different to any of the other examples. Put it this way: are the top thirty or so all fairly common? And are there any way down the list that should be up the top? More importantly: are there any very common examples that aren't on the list at all? If not, then I think you are right that for my use case I think I should be fine. Thank you for your help, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Conjugations of the Most-Used German Verbs](http://german.about.com/od/onlinecourses/fl/Conjugations-of-the-Most-Used-German-Verbs.htm) lists the 20 most common verbs with their most common forms and some example sentences. Each of these verbs is irregular, but the list is too short.

[Top 100 German verbs](http://www.thegermanprofessor.com/top-100-german-verbs/) lists the 100 most common verbs but without conjugated forms. However, there are many places where you can find the forms of the irregular verbs in that list, e.g. [List of irregular (strong) German verbs](https://jakubmarian.com/list-of-irregular-strong-german-verbs/).